Коректне використання множини для слів "сир" та "душ"
Мене хвилює, що слова "сир" та "душ" у множині звучать не зовсім правильно. Наприклад: "Купи мені, будь ласка, сири" або "До нас їдуть душі". Мені здається, що краще було б сказати: "Купи мені декілька пакунків сиру" або "До нас їдуть кабінки душу". Проте я не можу знайти джерела, які підтверджували б мої думки. Це більше інтуїтивні здогадки щодо правильності написання. Чи можете порекомендувати матеріали, які роз'яснюють правильне вживання слів у множині, особливо тих, які рідко використовуються або викликають неоднозначність?

Що саме вас бентежить? Що множина від душ (shower) та душа (soul) збігаються?

Щодо сирів: саме словосполучення «щодо сирів» звучить непогано, чи не так? Так само, як «м'які сири», «ферма виготовляє сири», «виготовлення сирів» тощо. Якщо цікавить саме «купити чогось», що це залишки віддільного відмінку (partitive case). Уточніть, будь ласка, запитання, щоб була можливість чітко на нього відповісти.

"Що множина від душ (shower) та душа (soul) збігаються?" - Так, це викликає неоднозначність. Якщо це коректно, використовувати в множині "сири" та "душі", тоді запитань немає. Дякую!
